# System overlay label is blocking DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-windowmanager

I need an app wide label that indicates debugging mode and if activated creates a bug report if tapped.
To have it on top of each activity I added it to the window manager. Works perfect for the app. But some configuration is done by a popup dialog fragment. It seems that they are active, but not visible to the user.
I've tried several layout parameter flags but didn't get it working.

Here is the code for adding the window:

```
final int LayoutParamFlags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
                LayoutParamFlags,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER;
windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
MyLabel label = new MyLabel();
windowManager.addView(label, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved the issue on my own by testing everything that came in my mind.

Changing the type from TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR to TYPE_TOAST did the trick for me. It is still over all activities and the dialog is also visible.
I had to add onAttachedToWindow to set the window token.

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    params.token = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().getWindowToken();
    windowManager.addView(bugReportingLabel, params);
}
```